# How to use Google push notification by Google drive APIs in Electron application?

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api, electron, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to receive Google push notifications on changes of files or one file in my drive using Electron, how do I do that?
I have tried following https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#registering-your-domain but turn out I have register my domain, any idea how do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive APIs > REST > [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) > Registering your domain

You use Google's [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) to show you are in charge of the domain. Not hard.